# Generic conversion operator templates and move semantics: any universal solution?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, move-semantics, explicit-conversion

This is a follow-up of [Explicit ref-qualified conversion operator templates in action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23377647/2644390). I have experimented with many different options and I am giving some results here in an attempt to see if there is any solution eventually.

Say a class (e.g. [any](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48344/39083)) needs to provide conversion to any possible type in a convenient, safe (no surprises) way that preserves move semantics. I can think of four different ways.

```
struct A
{
    // explicit conversion operators (nice, safe?)
    template<typename T> explicit operator T&&       () &&;
    template<typename T> explicit operator T&        () &;
    template<typename T> explicit operator const T&  () const&;

    // explicit member function (ugly, safe)
    template<typename T> T&&       cast() &&;
    template<typename T> T&        cast() &;
    template<typename T> const T&  cast() const&;
};

// explicit non-member function (ugly, safe)
template<typename T> T&&       cast(A&&);
template<typename T> T&        cast(A&);
template<typename T> const T&  cast(const A&);

struct B
{
    // implicit conversion operators (nice, dangerous)
    template<typename T> operator T&&       () &&;
    template<typename T> operator T&        () &;
    template<typename T> operator const T&  () const&;
};
```

The most problematic cases are to initialize an object or an rvalue reference to an object, given a temporary or an rvalue reference. Function calls work in all cases (I think) but I find them too verbose:

```
A a;
B b;

struct C {};

C member_move = std::move(a).cast<C>();  // U1. (ugly) OK
C member_temp = A{}.cast<C>();           // (same)

C non_member_move(cast<C>(std::move(a)));  // U2. (ugly) OK
C non_member_temp(cast<C>(A{}));           // (same)
```

So, I next experiment with conversion operators:

```
C direct_move_expl(std::move(a));  // 1. call to constructor of C ambiguous
C direct_temp_expl(A{});           // (same)

C direct_move_impl(std::move(b));  // 2. call to constructor of C ambiguous
C direct_temp_impl(B{});           // (same)

C copy_move_expl = std::move(a);  // 3. no viable conversion from A to C
C copy_temp_expl = A{};           // (same)

C copy_move_impl = std::move(b);  // 4. OK
C copy_temp_impl = B{};           // (same)
```

It appears that the `const&` overload is callable on an rvalue, which gives ambiguities, leaving copy-initialization with an implicit conversion as the only option.

However, consider the following less trivial class:

```
template<typename T>
struct flexi
{
    static constexpr bool all() { return true; }

    template<typename A, typename... B>
    static constexpr bool all(A a, B... b) { return a && all(b...); }

    template<typename... A>
    using convert_only = typename std::enable_if<
        all(std::is_convertible<A, T>{}...),
    int>::type;

    template<typename... A>
    using explicit_only = typename std::enable_if<
        !all(std::is_convertible<A, T>{}...) &&
        all(std::is_constructible<T, A>{}...),
    int>::type;

    template<typename... A, convert_only<A...> = 0>
    flexi(A&&...);

    template<typename... A, explicit_only<A...> = 0>
    explicit flexi(A&&...);
};

using D = flexi<int>;
```

which provides generic implicit or explicit constructors depending on whether the input arguments can be implicitly or explicitly converted to a certain type. Such logic is not that exotic, e.g. some implementation of `std::tuple` can be like that. Now, initializing a `D` gives

```
D direct_move_expl_flexi(std::move(a));  // F1. call to constructor of D ambiguous
D direct_temp_expl_flexi(A{});           // (same)

D direct_move_impl_flexi(std::move(b));  // F2. OK
D direct_temp_impl_flexi(B{});           // (same)

D copy_move_expl_flexi = std::move(a);  // F3. no viable conversion from A to D
D copy_temp_expl_flexi = A{};           // (same)

D copy_move_impl_flexi = std::move(b);  // F4. conversion from B to D ambiguous
D copy_temp_impl_flexi = B{};           // (same)
```

For different reasons, the only available option direct-initialization with an implicit conversion. However, this is exactly where implicit conversion is **dangerous**. `b` might actually contain a `D`, which may be a kind of container, yet the working combination is invoking `D`'s constructor as an exact match, where `b` behaves like a fake *element* of the container, causing a runtime error or disaster.

Finally, let's try to initialize an rvalue reference:

```
D&& ref_direct_move_expl_flexi(std::move(a));  // R1. OK
D&& ref_direct_temp_expl_flexi(A{});           // (same)

D&& ref_direct_move_impl_flexi(std::move(b));  // R2. initialization of D&& from B ambiguous
D&& ref_direct_temp_impl_flexi(B{});           // (same)

D&& ref_copy_move_expl_flexi(std::move(a));  // R3. OK
D&& ref_copy_temp_expl_flexi(A{});           // (same)

D&& ref_copy_move_impl_flexi = std::move(b);  // R4. initialization of D&& from B ambiguous
D&& ref_copy_temp_impl_flexi = B{};           // (same)
```

It appears that every use case has its own requirements and there is no combination that might work in all cases.

What's worse, all above results are with clang 3.3; other compilers and versions give slightly different results, again with no universal solution. For instance: [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef438661ee097085).

So: **is there any chance something might work as desired or should I give up conversion operators and stick with explicit function calls?**

Comment: I wonder about a `const&&` method which would resolve the ambiguity between `const&` and `&&`. For safety, it could still return a `const&`, but I suspect making it return `&&` (with a `const_cast`) would be as safe seeing as a `const` temporary seems meaningless.

Comment: @MatthieuM If I remember well, I have tried this to no avail. It appears that it only adds to ambiguities. Unfortunately, I have given up conversion operators altogether for now.

Comment: @iavr I've read the question a few times now and unfortunately I still can't figure out for each case what the desired functionality is. Which of all the cases you've enumerated do you want to work?

Comment: @MarkB Well, It would be nice if implicit conversion (everything containing `_impl`) worked in all cases (even if dangerous). Otherwise, I'd expect at least explicit conversion to work with direct initialization (everything containing `direct_` and `_expl`). Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard unfortunately does not have any special rule to resolve this particular ambiguity. The problem come from the fact that you are trying to overload on 2 different things: the type that the compiler is trying to convert to; and the kind of reference from which you are trying to convert from.

By introducing proxy classes, you can split the resolution in 2 steps. Step 1: decide if it's an r-value reference, an l-value reference, or a const l-value reference. Step 2: convert to any type, keeping the decision made in step 1 about the kind of reference. That way, you can use your solution with a cast() function but save you from having to specify the type:

```
struct A
{
    class A_r_ref
    {
        A* a_;
    public:
        A_r_ref(A* a) : a_(a) {}
        template <typename T> operator T&&() const&&;
    };

    struct A_ref
    {
        A* a_;
    public:
        A_ref(A* a) : a_(a) {}
        template <typename T> operator T&() const&&;
    };

    struct A_const_ref
    {
        const A* a_;
    public:
        A_const_ref(const A* a) : a_(a) {}
        template <typename T> operator const T&() const&&;
    };

    A_r_ref cast() && { return A_r_ref(this); }
    A_ref cast() & { return A_ref(this); }
    A_const_ref cast() const& { return A_const_ref(this); }
};
```

Comment: By answering, I finally found a use case for const&& :)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. By dropping the explicit type specification, `cast()` could even reduce to `operator*` or something. By the way, wouldn't just `&&` work for all conversion operators? Do you really need `const&&`? The type of reference is only relevant to the `A` object, to the type of data held by `A`, and to the type being cast to; not to the proxy object itself, right?

Comment: Well, the decision to use const&& on the proxy class conversion operator come from two things: First, I use an r-value reference because I want the proxy class to only be used as a temporary. Second, I don't modify the proxy class to accomplish its mission, so it can be const, so it *should* be const :) No more complicated than that.