# Bug in gcc-9 with implicit conversion via ref-qualified type-operators?

Tags: c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, rvalue-reference, ref-qualifier

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/z/P1v2ro):

```
struct Man
{
  operator int const&  () const&  { return           m_ban ; }
  operator int      && ()      && { return std::move(m_ban); }
  int m_ban;
};

void ff(int const& ) { std::cerr << "==== void ff(int const& )" << std::endl; }
void ff(int      &&) { std::cerr << "==== void ff(int      &&)" << std::endl; }
```

And later:

```
  Man man;
  ff(static_cast<Man const& >(man));
  ff(static_cast<Man      &&>(man));
```

This perfectly works with `gcc-8.3.0`, but `gcc-9.3.0` and all versions of `clang` and `msvc` can't pick the right `ff` for the second call. Is this a compiler bug? How the code should behave according to the standard?

Indeed, both type operators can be called for `Man&&`:

```
  static_cast<Man&&>(man).operator int const& ();
  static_cast<Man&&>(man).operator int      &&();
```

But because of the ref-qualification, the second one should be picked during the implicit conversion, right?

Comment: May I suggest a slightly simplified version of your formulation: https://godbolt.org/z/p255EN . It took me quite some time to parse your code to see what was important or not. This seems to relate to an actual change in the standard that I don't know of. I'd like to know what happens here

Comment: This code does not compile with -std=c++11 too. Other compilers also reject this with similar error message, so I suspect that gcc 9 fixed some bug introduced in the past.

Comment: @DanielFrużyński Yes, that is strange! Why that two type conversions should be considered ambiguous alternatives, when one of them has an "obvious" advantage, being ref-qualified with `&&` and the conversion operator being to be called on an rvalue?

Comment: Looks that this contains answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377647/explicit-ref-qualified-conversion-operator-templates-in-action

Comment: @DanielFrużyński Yes, seems so. Thus this is a bug with the standard, ranter than a bug with the compilers. `gcc-8` was doing perfectly well! I am hoping to find some hack option for `gcc-9` that would enable this.